# Can I deploy Durable Azure Function in ASE

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment, azure-durable-functions

Can I deploy Azure Durable Functions in to ASE (Azure Service Environment)? I know we can deploy Azure Functions in to ASE. But could not find details if Durable functions can be deployed.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't find any info specific for Durable Function because it's an extension of Azure Function and leverage the same Function runtime on which functions run. We are able to deploy Azure Functions to ASE hence Durable Function can't be an exception.