# Azure Durable Functions hosting

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Microsoft docs say Durable Functions is a extension of Azure Functions.

Does that mean Durable Functions **can be hosted in all the places an Azure  Function** can be hosted?

EDIT : Does it support to be deployed on any hosting option that Azure Functions could be deployed on?? Like Consumption, Premium , Dedicated and ASE ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I deploy Durable Azure Function in ASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53862313/can-i-deploy-durable-azure-function-in-ase)

Comment: No, I have clarified my question now...and want to know if it is able to be hosted in every option that Azure Functions can be hosted on...

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for Durable Functions:

Durable Functions is designed to work with all Azure Functions programming languages **but may have different minimum requirements for each language**. The following table shows the minimum supported app configurations:

| Language stack | Azure Functions Runtime versions | Language worker version | Minimum bundles version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .NET / C# / F# | Functions 1.0+ | In-process |  |
| Out-of-process | n/a |  |  |
| JavaScript/TypeScript | Functions 2.0+ | Node 8+ | 2.x bundles |
| Python | Functions 2.0+ | Python 3.7+ | 2.x bundles |
| Python (V2 prog. model) | Functions 4.0+ | Python 3.7+ | 3.15+ bundles |
| PowerShell | Functions 3.0+ | PowerShell 7+ | 2.x bundles |
| Java | Functions 4.0+ | Java 8+ | 4.x bundles |

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp-inproc

---

You can deploy Durable Function App to different plans:

- Consumption Plan
- Premium Plan
- Dedicated Plan

For Consumption Plan you should take into consideration the way how the Orchestrator function is billed:

> Orchestrator functions might replay several times throughout the lifetime of an orchestration. Each replay is viewed by the Azure Functions runtime as a distinct function invocation. For this reason, **in the Azure Functions Consumption plan you're billed for each replay of an orchestrator function**. Other plan types don't charge for orchestrator function replay
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-billing

---

Extra considerations:

> When running in the Azure Functions Consumption or Premium plans, the Azure Functions scale controller regularly polls all task-hub queues in the background. If a function app is under light to moderate scale, only a single scale controller instance will poll these queues. If the function app scales out to a large number of instances, more scale controller instances might be added. These additional scale controller instances can increase the total queue-transaction costs.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-billing#azure-storage-transactions

---

It's all in the official docs. Just google: "Durable Functions"

Comment: This helps. Is there a similar write-up for durable functions in ASEv3...in official docs? Nothing shows up as part of Google search.